# Is it true that $g'(x)\to0$ as $x\to b$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f(x)$ admits Taylor series representation (that is, $f$ is very smooth) for $x<b$ where $b$ is a finite real number and $f(x)<\infty$ for $x<b$ but $f(x)=\infty$ for all $x\geq b$. Further suppose $f(x)\to \infty$ and $f'(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to b-$.

Consider the function $g(x)=e^{-f(x)}$. Then by what I said, $g(x)$ will have Taylor series representation for all $x<b$ and $g(x)=0$ for all $x\geq b$ with $\lim_{x\to b-}g(x)=0$. Suppose $g,g',g''$ are integrable on any left neighborhood of $b$ (the integration set should exclude $b$). Then can I can conclude that $g'(x)\to 0$ as $x\to b-$?

So essentially what I have is $g'(x)=-f'(x)e^{-f(x)}$. Even if $f'(x)$ blasts off, $e^{-f(x)}$ should sort of dominate $f'(x)$ if the function is integrable and their derivative also is integrable. But I am not able to prove it. The statement $g'(x)\to0$ as $x\to b$ does not seem to be true if $g'$ is not integrable, but I have assumed $g'$ to be integrable. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the title.

Comment: I don't even know what it means to say that a *function* $f$ is $\infty$ for $x\ge b$. All I can do is work with $1/f$, say it's "very smooth" and $0$ for $x\ge b$. But OK, where in here do we know that the Taylor series of $f$ or $g$ even converges to the appropriate function on a neighborhood of each point $<b$? That said, I don't know why you're talking about Taylor series. I believe you just want to stipulate that $g$ is smooth (and $0$ for $x\ge b$).

Comment: Think of $f$ as a power series which diverges if $x\geq b$. And yes, I just want to stipulate $g$ is smooth. For this problem, the answer given by @metamorphy works, but kindly look at my comment to his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=-\log(1-x)$ is a counterexample (here $b=1$).

Comment: Thank you, but suppose I look at the function $h(x)=e^{-af(x)}$ where $a$ is a fixed positive number. Suppose $h',h''$ are all integrable around $x=b$. Then could I say that $h'(x)\to0$ as $x\to b-$? I think your example will not work if $a\in (0,1)$. But then $h''$ won't be integrable also.

Comment: I asked a modified question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3565116/is-it-true-that-hx-to0-as-x-to-b I realised that I would actually want to impose $f''(x)e^{-f(x)}$ to be integrable than just $g''$ to be integrable. If you can, please look into the question in this new thread.

Comment: @LandonCarter: (why the deletion?..) In this new setup, I would look at $$\int_x^b f''(y)e^{-f(y)}~dy=f'(y)e^{-f(y)}\Bigg|_x^b+\int_x^b\big(f'(y)\big)^2e^{-f(y)}~dy.$$

Comment: I know, I solved it actually, so I deleted the question.